# CSS variables overload

Tags: css, css-variables

So I'm new to CSS custom properties, so when I wrote this I really thought the div colors would change to darker:

```css
:root {
    --hue: 200;
    --sat: 33%;
    --light: 98%;
  
    --background: hsl(
      var(--hue),
      var(--sat),
      var(--light)
    );
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background);
}

div {
  --light: 0;
  background-color: var(--background);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>div</p>
    <p>div</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to use the same definition of the `--background` variable in different places, and just changing the `--hue`, `--sat` and `--light` where I want.